# Getting Permission denied (publickey). when starting hadoop cluster on AWS

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-web-services, mapreduce, cluster-computing

I am getting "Permission denied (publickey)" error when starting hadoop multi node cluster in AWS. But when i do ssh to each individual slave node without starting the cluster then i am able to access them. I did all the settings correct and checked twice.Any help on what may be wrong?

[image: getting error for all the slave nodes when doing start-all.sh to start Hadoop cluster]

Comment: try following these steps: http://allthingshadoop.com/2010/04/20/hadoop-cluster-setup-ssh-key-authentication/

Comment: Actually i already did all the SSH settings in all the node and as i told i am able to do ssh to individual slave nodes but when i am doing start-all.sh i am getting above error. May be its because i have created a new user i.e. hduser and did all the hadoop settings in it. Do i have to do it in ubuntu user or root user for every node. I am using AWS instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was i created a new user i.e. hduser and then configured hadoop in it.
I did all the setup(hadoop configuration) in Ubuntu user(default for ec2 Ubuntu instances) and it worked. I think its better to use default users's in AWS instances then creating any new one and then struggling to get permissions and other errors.